# Multiple images ok, but index of figures wrong

Tags: table-of-contents, errors, indexing

I'm triyng to put multiple images together and succeeded, but the problem comes when latex creates automatically the list of figures, it makes stranger things.... Edited adding a MWE

```
  \documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{Thesis}

\graphicspath{Figures/}  % Location of the graphics files (set up for graphics to be in PDF format)

% Include any extra LaTeX packages required
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} %para meter figuras bien bien
\usepackage{subcaption} %para meter figuras dentro de figuras

\begin{document}

\lhead{\emph{List of Figures}}  % Set the left side page header to "List if Figures"
\listoffigures  % Write out the List of Figures

        \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \subfloat[Resultado de la simulación en Scilab]{
            \label{fig:Vtoro-300V-SARAY}
            \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{contenido/Vtoro-300VSARAY.jpg}}
        \subfloat[Resultado de la simulación en Pspice]{
            \label{fig:Vtoro-300V}
            \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{contenido/Vtoro-300V.jpg}}
        \caption{Tensión del condensador del circuito secundario para $Vd=300 \, V$}
        \label{fig:Vtoro-dos-300V}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The result of the document is the following

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: packages `subcaption` and `subfig` exclude each other. you should use only one of them (do i doubt that with such preamble you can generate any result). you should clarify what is your problem with complete small document with `\listoffigures` and your picture. so far i can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: I edited the post with a MWE so you can understand it better, thanks for the interest

Comment: your code doesnt work. why see my comment above! so it is not clear what is your problem ... after removing undefined commands and error causing package i can't reproduce your problem. btw, which `Thesis` document class you use? most of them are of a low quality ...

Comment: an MWE is an example that other people can run, you need to use a standard class (or give a link to your Thesis.cls) and also try to reproduce just using `\includegraphics{example-image}` as that is an image people have, no one can see the problem iwith the code as posted now.